# How to copy an Array to an Excel Range in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, excel

How do I copy an Array to an Excel Range in C#? 
Why does the below code not work? 
If I assign it like this, then in each cell is the same value

```
Workbook workbook;
Worksheet worksheet;
List<double> flow = new List<double>();

workbook = excel.Workbooks.Open(filename);
worksheet = workbook.Worksheets.Add();

worksheet.Range[$"$A$1:$A{flow.count}"].Value = flow.ToArray();
```

Of course the list is filled with values. I have omitted this part here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

replace your last line with

```
Excel.Range range = sheetSource.UsedRange.Columns[columnIndx];
range.Value = application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(flow.ToArray());
```